# List of all the possible PHP errors

Tags: php

Sometimes, while coding in PHP we get parse or syntax errors like those:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/example/index.php on line 4
```

I would like to know, if there is a list of all possible errors that PHP interpreter can output. I've searched php.net, but couldn't find such thing. I need this list for academic purposes.

Comment: That error is probably just because you forgot to close your previous line.

Comment: @Laykes: I think you have to read the question again ;)

Comment: Yes, I did that intentionally, to get the example of an error. 
I'm more interested in getting the actual list of possible error messages, not in solving them - that's another issue :)

Comment: @Felix, I read the question correctly, I was just saying what that particular error could be caused by. I did not answer the question for the reason that I don't know the answer, but thought my comment might assist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there is no good way. Even the suggested grep for zend_Error() is useless. The errors of the kind you're showing in the question is mostly generated by the bison parser generator and PHP simply takes it from there. Similar things happen with errors reported by the operating system (like errors when opening files). The PHP developers can't really generate a good list for these as the errors depend on the operating system it is running on and versions used while compiling.

The only thing grepping for zend_error() and php_Error_docref() can show you is a general overview of possible error kinds but by far not all error messages.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if exists a comprehensive list of the possible PHP errors,
but about parser errors you should checkout the list of PHP Parser tokens

http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

here's what the manual says:

> *Various parts of the PHP language are represented internally by types like
>   T_SR. PHP outputs identifiers like
>   this one in parse errors, like "Parse
>   error: unexpected T_SR, expecting ','
>   or ';' in script.php on line 10."
>   You're supposed to know what T_SR
>   means. For everybody who doesn't know
>   that, here is a table with those
>   identifiers, PHP-syntax and references
>   to the appropriate places in the
>   manual.*

Comment: Thanks this list is quite useful for me too!

Comment: -1 this is good to know, but how is it related to error messages?

Comment: @Pekka: This link gives you the list of tokens by name, so you can see what token in your code invokes a parser error, thus you can solve your parse error, please read the short intro at the top of the page at http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: he is not about parser errors specifically if I understand him correctly. He wants a comprehensive list of *all* PHP errors for research.

Comment: ok let's put it this way: from the token list provided, Konstantin can generate himself a list of all possible PARSE ERRORS, provided the case he cannot find a comprehensive list of all possible errors. It's a partial solution to his problem

Answer (score 3):

i'm not aware of such a list, but you can always download or checkout php sources and do something like

```
 find . -name "*.c" | xargs grep "zend_error"
```

Comment: I've considered this. If there is no documentation on errors, I will have to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a list of all possible error types, this will help:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

This gives 1346 hits for me on the latest PHP source (including duplicates). It may be a good way to go, however the list far from complete due to the reasons outlined by @johannes.

On the other hand, it's going to be extremely difficult to define a specific *type* of parse error anyway, as I imagine they are compiled by parser during runtime, and are not listed anywhere in the source.

Can you elaborate on what you need this for? Maybe you can define a "sub-class" of errors that is already sufficient for what your need.