# PHP Runtime error list

Tags: php, runtime-error

I wonder if a list of php runtime errors exist?

And if not, please tell me: are these php runtime errors?

- Calling unset variable
- Calling undefined method

Edit: I know how to handle errors well, this question is purely theoretical - I want to know how to call these errors in general.

Comment: How to call these errors? What does that mean? You mean "what to call these errors"? Not sure what you're asking. Those are all runtime errors with different error levels: E_NOTICE (unset variable), E_ERROR (undefined method). Is your question about getting a list of errors and their levels?

Comment: @Juan I was in need of list of errors php that can cause php application to fail after the compile phase. Thanks for clarifying the error levels of unset var/method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definitive list of PHP runtime errors.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355164/list-of-all-possible-php-errors).  However, most PHP errors typically lend themselves to the following:

- Arithmetic errors
- Calls to undefined functions
- Interaction with MySQL or other databases
- Interaction with files
- Network services

As drew said above, calling an unset variable won't typically cause a fatal error.  PHP will generally assume NULL for its use.

Answer (score 0):

An unset variable is a notice only. Depending on your error reporting settings, the user won't see this and it will return null (script will then proceed as normal).

Calling an undefined function will throw a fatal error which will normally stop the processing of the script there.

For error handling, check out the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I asked for. I know how to handle errors well. The problem here is purely theoretical and I wanted to know how I should call these errors. Thanks for your effort anyway.