# PHP: how to deal with exceptions in the case below

Tags: php, exception

I don't have enough experience with PHP and programming at all, so I want to know, what the best decision in my situation is.
Here is my code sample:

```
public static function isAscii($string, $type, $length = -1)
    {
        if (!is_string($string))
            throw new InternalException(ExceptionMessage::invalidFunctionParameterType(__CLASS__, __METHOD__));

        if ($length !== -1 && !Str::isValidLength($string, $length))
            return FALSE;

        $ascii_array = Constants::asciiRegex();

        if (!preg_match($ascii_array[$type], $string))
            return FALSE;

        return TRUE;
    }
```

I want to ensure that key `$type` exists for array `$ascii_array`. What is the best way to do that?

I can offer two decisions:

1. The simplest. Just check key existence manually with `array_key_exists()` function. If key doesn't exist - throw an exception, also manually. But I think that is not a good idea and checking this condition is redundant, because PHP compiler will generate warning if I don’t write anything (Notice: Undefined index:) and I want to use this somehow. I found there are some predefined exceptions like `OutOfBoundsException` and `OutOfRangeException`, it would be easy just to use them like in Java, but it seems that PHP doesn’t throw these exceptions, only warnings and errors.
2. Use `set_error_handler()` function to 'convert' errors and warnings to exceptions. But there is another problem - how can I handle all possible errors? I tried to find the complete list of PHP errors and warnings, but [it doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355164/list-of-all-possible-php-errors).
   So I have no idea how to solve this problem, please help me.
   Thanks in advance, hope you will understand my question even with my poor English level.

P.S. this is an array with regular expressions for different types of ascii strings.[image]

Comment: if you want to check, if something is in an array or not, use `in_array` - i dont get the point what you are trying to do with exceptions here? i.e. wheres the difference between returning `false` and throwing an exception? Or lets say: What is your desired outcome? Should the app behave different?

Comment: If you are simply trying to tell if a string is ascii or not, your function is wayyyy to complex for that. If that's not what you are doing, you should choose a different function name.

Comment: I agree, you are a bit overengineering here. This kind of complexity at this stage of your application design won't help in the future.

Comment: @crush There are several combinations of ascii symbols, that's why I have an array with regular expressions for each type.

Comment: @dognose I just want this method to throw exception (OutOfBoundsException or OutOfRangeException probably) and I don't want to throw it manually after checking condition with `in_array()` or `array_key_exists()` function.

Comment: @crush I added screenshot to my post with this array, I find it very convenient to test strings in such way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding this question correctly -
Are you basically asking if there is a natural internal exception to adopt instead of running your own exception?

Or are you just not aware you can do something like:

```
try
{
    //some code to try
    if (!in_array($type, $ascii_array)) {
        throw new Exception('type not in ascii array');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die ('my custom exception message: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

if i missed the point, let me know and I may update.

As for a reason to not throw your own exceptions... I can't say I know of a real benefit to this. It would seem to me that in_array() is perfectly acceptable and throwing exceptions may just be personal preference and not necessarily a worthwhile concern for performance.

*EDIT*

Considering my answer and the question, it is noteworthy that this answer was accepted likely due to the conclusion in the comments that PHP does not allow you to declare functions that throw exceptions like Java does. Simply put.

So this answer is to serve only that purpose. Can PHP declare a function that throws an exception? No, not by default. You have to try and catch the exceptions yourself within the function.

Comment: Well, I wrote that I don't want to throw exception manually, like you wrote, because I supposed there was a better way to do that using natural internal exception mechanism. This would reduce amount of code. But if there is no chance to do that - well, then I'll check conditions and throw exceptions in method's code.

Comment: I'll try to explain more carefully. I would like to write code here like in Java, just like that `public static function isAscii($string, $type, $length = -1) throws OutOfRangeException`. If something like that is possible, there is no need in writing extra conditions in my method's code. I don't know all the possibilities of PHP, that's why I asked this question. If that's not possible – no problems, just wanted to ensure.

Comment: I think "better way" may be a matter of perspective. As far as I know, php doesn't have a means for defining functions like Java, and that's ok seeing as they're just different languages. Succinctly, the answer would be "no" that you cannot do this and have to rely on the self definition. I'm not the end all authority on this, but in my 8+ years of PHP and numerous frameworks, CMS packages and adopted code I've never known of this being possible.