# Searching for a comprehensive list with all PHP error messages. Bugtracker

Tags: php, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm searching for a list will all possible PHP error messages. Google couldn't help me out this time.

**Example:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ... in ... on line ...
Warning: require_once(...) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ... on line ...
Warning: Illegal offset type in ... on line ...
```

and much more of such erros...

According to the php.net http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php PHP is using tokens to generate error messages. But i still don't understand how to use them to generate an error message like

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function T_SOME_TOKEN in T_SOME_TOKEN on line 666
```

Where should i search for such an error generator? I assume that it is hidden  somewhere in PHP's source code, but i have no idea where to start.

The purpose is to build an PHP error parser which would monitor server error messages (if they are enabled) and check for PHP script updates:

```
Script "foo.php" which returns multiple errors

Scan 1 (time t1):
    PHP Error on line 1000
    PHP Error on line 1200

Scan 2 (time t2):
    PHP Error on line 1010
    PHP Error on line 1210
```

1010 - 1000 = 10 lines of code were added (somewhere between lines 0 and 1010). By using this approach and knowledge of which bug was fixed at which time it is possible to make kind of **"PHP error based black box reverse engineering"** of a given PHP script (if there are enough other reproducible PHP bugs in such script) (e.g. buggy game engine).

Comment: I found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355164/list-of-all-the-possible-php-errors but there is nothing said about how these errors are generated.

Comment: inspathx project: https://github.com/Occupy4Elephants/inspathx + bison parser generator