# How identical or changing are PHP error messages across PHP versions?

Tags: php, error-handling, runtime-error

SPIP (FOSS CMS) compiler creates a PHP code out of the SPIP source. Due to PHP increasing strictness, new errors appear in the PHP executed code (eg bad argument count or bad argument type) that sometimes can't be detected at compile time. I wish to try-catch PHP error messages, analyse them through regexps and output SPIP-source relating messages instead of PHP compiled source relating native messages.

I now wonder : how consistent are PHP error messages across versions ?
New features and new strictness require new messages, but do error messages for the same error change often across PHP versions ? In such a case it would be more difficult to analyse messages and another way of doing might be better suited.

Is there somewhere a "release log" of PHP error messages evolution specificaly ?

How have other tools (that compile some meta script to PHP) tackled this issue ?

Comment: I don't think there's a guarantee, but I also don't think they change error messages needlessly. I'm not aware of a registry of error messages or a separate change log of them.

Comment: I think error messages are also internationalized, so they might reword them if someone thinks a translation is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of all the possible PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355164/list-of-all-the-possible-php-errors)

Comment: @nosurs I read there is "no good way" to get all errors ; i read " the errors depend on the operating system it is running on and versions used while compiling". So it rather unfavors this way of doing.

Comment: @Barmar : I read on the web that some PEAR errors are internationalized, but on all servers i've been working in France, core PHP error messages were all english language. This makes me think that PHP internals arent internationalized.

Answer (score 0):

Not a totaly satisfying answer but PHP error messages are spread across its source : there is no such thing as a strings file (centralizing the error messages) that could be versionned.